# Rails: List records in Dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got some Users in my DB with a column called "role". The role contains either admin, manager or user as the value. 
Now I want to loop through this column and list only the respective role once and not all in a Dropdown. The current dropdown lists something like:

- admin
- user
- user
- user
- user
- manager

But I want it to be only like

- admin
- user
- manager

This is my current code:

```
    <%= f.label :role %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:role, User.all, :role, :role, {prompt:true},    {class: 'form-control'}) %>
```

Any Ideas? Thank you guys!

Comment: `User.distinct(:role).pluck(:role)` will give you just an array of distinct roles in users table with efficient query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do so, [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) the `User` model by uniq roles:

```
<%= f.select(:role, User.pluck(:role).uniq, {prompt:true}, {class: 'form-control'}) %>
```

Comment: There I get a "wrong number of arguments (3 for 4..6)" Error. :(

Comment: @Andrey Deineko now I get a "undefined method `role' for "user":String" Error

Comment: @Harakiri It's because you've used collection slect, check out now (it is just select now)